MeiliSearch multi-search route throwing 404 error
I have setup a docker + laravel (v10) + meilisearch (v1.7) setup
in Postman using an index search.  Meilisearch manage to return some values
curl --location 'http://localhost:7700/indexes/d99f2662-5d20-4157-b45f-91fb810f1d7b-applications-index/search' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer masterKey' \
--data '{
    "q": "FR",
    "limit": 20
}'

However, using the multi-search route , I'm getting a 404 error.  Already searching for the fix for like hours now.  Is there a switch to enable this.
curl --location 'http://localhost:7700/multi-search' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer masterKey' \
--data ' {"queries": [
        {
          "indexUid": "d99f2662-5d20-4156-b45e-92fb810f1d7b-applications-index",
          "q": "0001"
        }
    ]
 }'

